# switch statement not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am experiencing an issue where a javascript function, is getting a var `selectedMonth` which is a string, and the alert dialog is showing the value of the string but for some reason the switch statement is not working. I am experiencing this issue on page load, it does work with `<select>` onchange listener.

in this case, i get alert `Dezember` but switch statement december doesn't get called.

```js
function showDropDown(selectedMonth) {

  alert(selectedMonth);

  var settings = {
    "url": "",
    "method": "GET",
    "timeout": 0,
  };

  switch (selectedMonth) {
    case 'Januar':
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/1"
      break;
    case 'Februar':
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/2"
      break;
    case "März":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/3"
      break;
    case "April":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/4"
      break;
    case "Mai":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/5"
      break;
    case "Juni":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/6"
      break;
    case "Juli":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/7"
      break;
    case "August":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/8"
      break;
    case "September":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/9"
      break;
    case "Oktober":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/10"
      break;
    case 'November':
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/11"
      break;
    case 'Dezember':
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/12"
      break;
    default:
      // code block
  }

  alert(settings.url);
}

    $(".New_Plant_Month").change(function () {

        // Fetching Value
        var month = $(this).val();
        showDropDown(month);

    });

// show months
$(document).ready(function() {


  var month = $(".New_Plant_Month  option:selected").text() + "";
  showDropDown(month);

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var d = new Date();
    var months = ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"];
    var monthName = months[new Date(d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - i)).getMonth()];

    //console.log(monthName);
    $('.New_Plant_Month').append($("<option>").val(monthName).text(monthName));
}

  


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="New_Plant_Month">
</select>
```

**Preview**
[image]

asp.net core code

```
        <!-- asp-items="New plant SelectList"-->
        <div class="form-group">

            <label asp-for="NewPlantMonth" class="control-label">Neue Pflanzen</label>
            <!-- asp-items="NewsSelectList"-->
            <select class="form-control Shoplist New_Plant_Month" onchange="showDropDown(this.value)" data-search="true" asp-for="NewPlantMonth">
                <option value="NewPlantMonth"> @{var selectedValue = Model.NewPlantMonth != null ? Model.NewPlantMonth : "Bitte Monat auswählen"; } @selectedValue </option>
</select>

<span asp-for="NewPlantMonth" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Comment: How are you calling the function? `showDropDown('Dezember')`?

Comment: code seems ok by calling the function directly

Comment: @NicholasTower i added the code where i call `showDropDown(month)`. I call it on page load and the value is taken from `<select>` option.

Comment: Actually the code is not in a good style... Try not to do so. For example, you can simply have a map or list from "month name" to "month index"

Comment: your code works ... the function creates this `settings` object that it does nothing with, but the code alerts the correct values - the `url`s are all invalid too, but since you do nothing with the url or anything in settings, then that's not an issue

Comment: Why don't you add it as a code snippet here and see for yourself that it works just fine?

Comment: I use settings url to send ajax request. I just posted the relevant code. And in my case the switch statement is not working. For `alert(settings.url);` i get empty string

Comment: My guess is you want to change `var month = $(".New_Plant_Month  option:selected").text()+"";` to `let month = $('.New_Plant_Month').text();`,assuming that's the `<select>` itself, but I don't see your HTML, so how should I know? Maybe `.val()`?

Comment: Edited your question, so you have a working snippet...

Comment: Its working snippet now, btw the code still doesn't work on page load. the important thing for me is that it doesn't work on page load.

Comment: You are trying to get a selected option on page load **before** you even create the options. Your whole switch is over complicated when all you need is the index of the monthname in the array to use for the last number in the url

Comment: @charlietfl the option is default value coming from database, so i double checked that and that doesn't seem to be the reason. btw if that's the case the alert should also be empty value.

Comment: That's a `<select></select>`? Looks like an `<input type='text' />` to me.

Comment: @StackSlave i added <select> part of the code

Comment: When I hit "Run code snippet", it works as expected. What am I missing here?

Comment: ```
var months = {
      'Januar': 1,
      'Februar': 2,
      'März': 3,
      'April': 4,
      /*... add the rest of the months*/
    }
     settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/"+months[selectedMonth];
```

Comment: Here is the sandbox link of your exact code. It works like a charm. What's the problem? https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-mountain-i27w1?file=/index.html

Comment: The only thing passed to an EventListening function is the EventObject. Looks like @BilhasryRamadhony gave you an example you can work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only fix i found to this was to trigger`<select>` via jquery `change` listener programmatically on page load otherwise the `var selectedMonth` in `switch` never passed.. as shown in above gif screenshot.

anyways here is the fix.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
              .
              .
              .

            $('.New_Plant_Month')
                .trigger('change');

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you need is an event listener, when user change the dropdown, you will call different api. Here I add event listener, when the dropdown change it will call your showDropdown function.

```
$('.New_Plant_Month').change((e) => {
 showDropDown(e.target.value);
})
```

Here is the code

```js
function showDropDown(selectedMonth) {

console.log(selectedMonth);

  var settings = {
    "url": "",
    "method": "GET",
    "timeout": 0,
  };

  switch (selectedMonth) {
    case 'Januar':
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/1"
      break;
    case 'Februar':
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/2"
      break;
    case "März":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/3"
      break;
    case "April":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/4"
      break;
    case "Mai":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/5"
      break;
    case "Juni":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/6"
      break;
    case "Juli":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/7"
      break;
    case "August":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/8"
      break;
    case "September":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/9"
      break;
    case "Oktober":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/10"
      break;
    case 'November':
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/11"
      break;
    case 'Dezember':
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/12"
      break;
    default:
      // code block
  }

  alert(settings.url);
}


// show months
$(document).ready(function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var d = new Date();
    var months = ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"];
    var monthName = months[new Date(d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - i)).getMonth()];

    //console.log(monthName);
    $('.New_Plant_Month').append($("<option>").val(monthName).text(monthName));
}
  var month = $(".New_Plant_Month  option:selected").text() + "";

showDropDown(month);

  $('.New_Plant_Month').change((e) => {
     showDropDown(e.target.value);
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="New_Plant_Month"></select>
```

Comment: onChange listener is working, i have mentioned that in the post also, i just haven't posted the code for that part.

Answer (score 0):

The order of codes gotta be a bit different - like that:

```js
function showDropDown(selectedMonth) {

  alert(selectedMonth);

  var settings = {
    "url": "",
    "method": "GET",
    "timeout": 0,
  };

  switch (selectedMonth) {
    case 'Januar':
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/1"
      break;
    case 'Februar':
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/2"
      break;
    case "März":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/3"
      break;
    case "April":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/4"
      break;
    case "Mai":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/5"
      break;
    case "Juni":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/6"
      break;
    case "Juli":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/7"
      break;
    case "August":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/8"
      break;
    case "September":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/9"
      break;
    case "Oktober":
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/10"
      break;
    case 'November':
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/11"
      break;
    case 'Dezember':
      settings.url = "https://sslbeta.de/api/plantsearchapi/latest/12"
      break;
    default:
      // code block
  }

  alert(settings.url);
}


// show months
$(document).ready(function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var d = new Date();
    var months = ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"];
    var monthName = months[new Date(d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - i)).getMonth()];

    //console.log(monthName);
    $('.New_Plant_Month').append($("<option>").val(monthName).text(monthName));

  }

var month = $(".New_Plant_Month  option:selected").text() + "";
  showDropDown(month);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="New_Plant_Month"></select>
```

Comment: actually that's not the issue i am having. I updated the code at stackoverflow and accidentally put the code inside loop. It is outside the loop, so that is not the reason. Btw thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, To switch statement not working in javascript

```
<html>
   <body>   
      <script type = "text/javascript">
         <!--
            var grade = 'C';
            document.write("Entering switch block<br />");
            switch (grade) {
               case 'A': document.write("Good job<br />");
               break;
            
               case 'B': document.write("Pretty good<br />");
               break;
            
               case 'C': document.write("Passed<br />");
               break;
            
               case 'D': document.write("Not so good<br />");
               break;
            
               case 'F': document.write("Failed<br />");
               break;
            
               default:  document.write("Unknown grade<br />")
            }
            document.write("Exiting switch block");
         //-->
      </script>      
      <p>Set the variable to different value and then try...</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.

Comment: normally switch statement works, but in my case it doesn't seem to work